# Input type number doesn't render the value from edit mode

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form which have input field type number.
So, when i try to edit that form it shows all the value from the database.
But in Input type field it doesn't show any value . Even if there is value when i inspect but it doesnt show in browser.

```
 <input type="number" value="@if(!empty($salary->salary)){{$salary->salary}} @endif" name="salary" class="form-control" id="inputsalary" placeholder="salary">
```

value inside input type number it doesn't show in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="number" value="{{ $salary->salary ? $salary->salary : ''}}" name="salary" class="form-control" id="inputsalary" placeholder="salary">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why? Can you please explain.

Comment: This is a default shorthand format to echo values with condition. Do not forget to vote up if it helps.